# Allowing for >1 input on simple continuous time system

Tags: drake

I am trying to recreate the pendulum example found in source into binary for practice. To do this, I am modifying the simple_continuous_time_system.cc example that comes with the binary installation. However, when I try to add an input (from 0 to 1) I get this error:

in DoValidateAllocatedLeafContext(): condition 'this->get_num_input_ports() <= 1' failed.

this is because the simple continuous time example class does not allow for an input...I think. So now I don't know where to go from here. help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the DeclareInputPort statement in the constructor of the PendulumPlant in examples/pendulum?